# Dafny Question: How to describe an array as incremental?

Tags: dafny

The following is a Binary Search algorithm verified with Dafny:

```
method BinarySearch(a: array<int>, key: int) returns (index: int)
    requires forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]

    ensures 0 <= index ==> index < a.Length && a[index] == key
    ensures index < 0 ==> forall k :: 0 <= k < a.Length ==> a[k] != key
{
    var l, r := 0, a.Length;
    while l < r
        invariant 0 <= l <= r <= a.Length
        invariant forall i ::
         0 <= i < a.Length && !(l <= i < r) ==> a[i] != key
    {
        var m := (l + r) / 2;
        if a[m] < key {
            l := m + 1;
        } else if key < a[m] {
            r := m;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The pre-condition `requires forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]` describes the array as incremental. However, when I replace it with another expression:`requires forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i - 1] <= a[i]`, the verification failed, and the compiler said the invariant `invariant forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && !(l <= i < r) ==> a[i] != key` cannot be proved.

To me, the two expressions show the same meaning. What's the difference?

`requires forall i, j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j]` -> `requires forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i - 1] <= a[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the first form *explicitly* encodes the transitive relationship between elements, whilst the second does not.  Transitivity is needed to show, for example, that `a[l] <= a[m]` in the loop body.  Thus, in the second form, the verifier must extract the transitive relationship itself (which it cannot).

We can see this by trimming the example down:

```dafny
method BinarySearch(a: array<int>, key: int) returns (index: int)
requires forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i-1] <= a[i]
{
    //
    assert forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j];
    //
    return -1;
}
```

This assertion fails to verify.  However, we can get it to verify by adding in the missing transitivity information using a lemma:

```dafny
lemma LemmaTransitivity(a: seq<int>)
requires forall i :: 0 < i < |a| ==> a[i-1] <= a[i]
ensures forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |a| ==> a[i] <= a[j]
{
    if |a| > 2 {
        LemmaTransitivity(a[1..]);
        assert a[0] <= a[1];
    }
}

method BinarySearch(a: array<int>, key: int) returns (index: int)
requires forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i-1] <= a[i]
{
    //
    LemmaTransitivity(a[..]);
    assert forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] <= a[j];
    //
    return -1;
}
```

This now verifies.  Furthermore, we can use it to verify your original example.  **Note**: `a[..]` converts an `array` into a `seq` which is just an easier form to work with in the lemma.

Comment: I have another question that maybe you'd like to help me with. The invariant says `invariant 0 <= l <= r <= a.Length`, in the extreme case, l = r = a.Length and m = (l + r) / 2 = a.Length, which would trigger an out of index through a[m]. However, Dafny believes a[m] is safe. How does it make that judgment?

Comment: Hi, right but you also know the loop condition `l < r` is true within the body of the loop.  This in turn implies that `m < l` because division rounds down.